# Select option change css

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

how can I change the css of another element when I click any option in the select option
Note : The data comes from the database into the select option

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in javascript,

```js
const yourSelector = document.getElementById('yourSelector');
yourSelector.addEventListener('change', () => 
   document.querySelector(yourAwesomeElement).style..... // whatever you want
)
```

this code will change the css of another element when you will click on any option of the selector.

Comment: I cannot add id because my option comes from database

Comment: <select  name="Questions2TypeId" id="questtype">

                                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.questtype)
                                {
                                    <option  
                           value="@item.QuestionTypeId">@item.QuestionOpenorClose</option>
                                }
                            </select>       this way

Comment: well, the id here will be the id for the selector so it will be `questtype`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is below: value="@item.QuestionTypeId" that I set as 1,2,3,4

```
<select name="Questions2TypeId" id="questtype">
    <option selected="selected" disabled>-- Select --</option>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.questtype)
    { <option value="@item.QuestionTypeId">@item.QuestionOpenorClose</option> }
</select>
<p >Click to see the effect.</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#questtype').change(function() { //change click to change color
   
  if ( $("option:selected", this).is(':selected')) { //check which option is selected
 
    var optionValue = $("option:selected").attr('value');
    if(optionValue == 1) {
       
        $('p').attr('style','color:blue;')
    }
   if(optionValue == 2) {
     
        $('p').attr('style','color:red;')
    }
    if(optionValue == 3) {
   
        $('p').attr('style','color:pink;')
    }
    if(optionValue == 4) {
   
        $('p').attr('style','color:green;')
    }
  }
 
})
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

[Note]
You can refer to:  [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)to use $( "p" ).addClass(  );or $( "p" ).removeClass( ) according to your class set in style.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
    <option value="item0">--Select an Item--</option>
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>

<select id="size">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>
```